# What should we do with the video and video-recording tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Now that Video is no longer sharing space with Audio, there's no need to distinguish a question as being about either with a tag. Hence:

[video](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video)

... is basically now a useless meta tag, since *every* question on the site should conceivably be about video, minus any that were missed during the migration period. It should be able to be burninated rather easily, but there are some cases where it's the *only* tag, so a glance through them would be extremely helpful if you've got some time.

That brings us to no longer need to differentiate between audio and video *recording* as well, which means:

[video-recording](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-recording) could conceivably just become [recording], but I don't see the harm in leaving it the way it is. As the system applies popular tags to the HTML `<title>` element, keeping it as it is might be better for SEO.

Thoughts? This is (fortunately) the bulk of the post-migration cleanup.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure. Video is probably too general, but video recording probably still fits the way it is. Video production could still include a pretty wide range of things including some amount of audio, motion capture, cg, effects, etc. So clarification on video recording is probably still useful, even though video is probably too general.